# Override a .properties file contained within a .jar library

Tags: java, maven, properties, jar, overriding

I'm struggling to find an answer to this that's not relying on Spring or anything similar.

I maintain a Java library which provides an abstraction away from a server, this library is built using maven. In order to define the connection details (which are currently hard coded) I want to introduce a .properties file to allow for easy customisation, however I want to provide sensible defaults within the .jar itself, but allow people to override specific properties if necessary.

My current maven structure is something like this...

```
src/java/com/site/package/cfg/MyLibraryConfig.java
src/resources/com/site/package/cfg/MyLibraryConfig.properties
```

I'm currently using `getResourceAsStream("MyLibraryConfig.properties")` from within the MyLibraryConfig class to load the properties file, and that's working fine.

Is there a way to allow people using my .jar to put a file (e.g. MyLibraryConfigOverride.properties) outside my .jar which is then picked up and used? I'd only want them to override the specific properties they wanted to though, not the entire file. For example it's quite normal to change the server hostname but use all the standard ports.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes when you load your overriden property you will get another inputstream and you can get all the properties from it similar to what you had in MyLibraryConfig properties. And post that you can decide which property you want to override and which dont.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd not try to overwrite a file, but rather hardcoded devine my defaults and offer a possibility to overwrite these defaults via optional file like:

```
Properties data = new Properties();
data.setProperty("a", "sensitive default");
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("MyLibraryConfig.properties");
if (in != null) {
  data.load(in);
  in.close();
}
```

But of course you can put your defaults in a file, too, if you prefer. In this case just use different names. Like this:

```
Properties data = new Properties();
InputStream defaults = getClass().getResourceAsStream("defaults.properties");
data.load(defaults);
defaults.close();
InputStream overwrites= getClass().getResourceAsStream("overwrites.properties");
if (overwrites!= null) {
  data.load(overwrites);
  overwrites.close();
}
```

This adds additional complexity and you have to decide whether this will pay for you.